# Resources on the soft aspects of modelling

Tags: modeling, applications, or-careers

Usually, the modeling involves those steps :

Fuzzy Description ----(1)----> Clearer Description -----(2)-----> Mathematical model.

Of course, it's not linear and a lot of iteration and re-modeling is involved.

I am looking for resources on the (1) part. How to do the problem discovery? How to ask the customer the right questions? Are there some tools/methods that help with that? etc.

It's more like the soft aspects of modelling and not about writing mathematical equations down.

Comment: Maybe, these links, ([link1](https://www.optaplanner.org/blog/2016/04/18/7WaysToFailYourOptimizationProject.html), [link2](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/2953/what-are-the-reasons-or-industry-projects-fail)), would be helpful. Also, by searching in the community, you can find other related questions and answers.